# Lottery Pick 1 out of 10 or 10 out of 100 which is better

Tags: probability

To win the lottery you must pick the one winning ticket.
Given the option of drawing 1 out of 10 tickets or 10 out of 100 tickets to win which is the better option?  Are they both 1 out of 10 or is it better to pick 1 out of 100 first, then 1 out of 99, then 1 out of 98 (assuming you don't pick the winner) up to your 10 picks.  Both should be 10% but I don't know why the 10 separate picks out of 100 doesn't add up to more than 10%. Can someone explain the probability equation for this?

Comment: It is important that your $10$ picks are distinct (i.e. without replacement)

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think it's not the same?

It's easier to count the probability that you will NOT win.

In the first case it is $P_1=\frac9{10}$

In the second case it is:

$P_2=\frac{99}{100}\times\frac{98}{99}\times\frac{97}{98}\times\frac{96}{97}\times\frac{95}{96}\times\frac{94}{95}\times\frac{93}{94}\times\frac{92}{93}\times\frac{91}{92}\times\frac{90}{91}=\frac{90}{100}=P_1$

Answer (score 0):

Statistically your odds of winning indeed are increased by picking 10 times out of 100 assuming the 10 picks are distinct and without replacement.

1 pick of 10 = 10% Chance of selecting the winning ticket

1 of 100= 1%
1 of  99= 1.01%
1 of 98 = 1.02%
1 of 97 = 1.03%
1 of 96 = 1.04%
1 of 95 = 1.05%
1 of 94 = 1.06%
1 of 93 = 1.07%
1 of 92 = 1.08%
1 of 91 = 1.10%

The odds of picking the winning ticket in this manner is 10.46%

Comment: May you clarify your question and your thoughts? At the moment it sounds jumbled up a bit..